# What is wrong with my PDO request?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to make a simple function for insert array in my database with PDO.

```
   <?php
require_once($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . '/include/config/database.php');
/**
 * Database
 */
class Database {

    function __construct() 
    {

    }
    function insertArray($array, $table)
    {
        global $bdd;
        $i = 1;

        foreach ($array as $key => $currVal) 
        {
            if ($i == count($array))
                $keyVal .= ':'.$key;
            else
                $keyVal .= ':'.$key.', ';
            $i++;
        }
        $arrayKeyValue = implode(", ", array_keys($array));
        $req = $bdd->prepare('INSERT INTO '.$table.'('.$arrayKeyValue.') VALUES('.$keyVal.')');
        $req->execute($array);
        die('DONE');
    }
}

?>
```

But no data is inserted and i don't have any error in php or with pdo error...

Someone know what i make wrong?

thanks

PS: Sorry for my bad English

SQL setting & connection

```
   <?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=csgo', 'csgo', 'password removed', array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8', PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING));
?>
```

variable content:

```
$array 
array(5) {
  ["screen_name"]=>
  string(4) "test"
  ["avatar_big"]=>
  string(15) "test_avatar.png"
  ["avatar_small"]=>
  string(16) "small_avatar.png"
  ["steam_id"]=>
  int(991)
  ["last_connection"]=>
  int(156121)
}
$keyVal
string(69) ":screen_name, :avatar_big, :avatar_small, :steam_id, :last_connection"
$arrayKeyValue
string(64) "screen_name, avatar_big, avatar_small, steam_id, last_connection"
```

SQL request:

```
INSERT INTO user(screen_name, avatar_big, avatar_small, steam_id, last_connection) VALUES(:screen_name, :avatar_big, :avatar_small, :steam_id, :last_connection)
```

Comment: What is the actual SQL string being passed to `prepare`?

Comment: PDO will error silently by default. Set your `$bdd` object to throw exceptions, in `database.php` after connecting:  `$bdd->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`

Comment: `... VALUES("'.$keyVal.'")');` You are missing `"` (quotation marks) around the values

Comment: You should read [documentation for PDO::prepare](http://php.net/manual/fr/pdo.prepare.php)

Comment: And post the output of `print_r($array)`.  Also, store the `INSERT` statement into a variable and `echo $variable;` so we can see what the string ultimately contains.

Comment: Thanks for your anserws i updated my post with my sql setting

Comment: I only want to add that as a generic function it would be a good idea to have a quote function for identifiers too. Every reserved word, every special character in a table or column name will break this function.

Comment: @UnamataSanatarai I try with or without "", nothing work.

Comment: Sorry - I missed that you already had `ERRMODE_WARNING` in your connection string. Change that to `ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` to make it fail. Otherwise, check `var_dump($bdd->errorInfo())`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I just add a space between user and () this does'nt work :-(

Comment: @BastienBastWeber Then you'll need to debug with `$bdd->errorInfo()` or make it throw an exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally find the solution, first i make a var_dump of the errCode (don't know this function before sry)

```
var_dump($req->errorCode());
```

he returning  the error code: 42S02

So for fix that a simple solution just add:

```
$bdd->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score -1):

Try escaping your table and column names with `

```
function insertArray($array, $table)
{
    global $bdd;
    $i = 1;

    foreach ($array as $key => $currVal) 
    {
        if ($i == count($array))
            $keyVal .= ':'.$key;
        else
            $keyVal .= ':'.$key.', ';
        $i++;
    }
    $arrayKeyValue = "`" . implode("`, `", array_keys($array)) . "`";
    $req = $bdd->prepare('INSERT INTO `'.$table.'`('.$arrayKeyValue.') VALUES('.$keyVal.')');
    $req->execute($array);
    die('DONE');
}
```

Comment: Those `:` should generate [named parameters](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php#refsect1-pdo.prepare-examples), I'm sure.

Comment: I have the same issue with this request. about the sql injection i think this is secure, i use ":" to bind value with array key ($array)